# How to implement mock backend service and real backend service exist simultaneously in Angular2/4

Tags: angular

In the angualr4 project, how to  the part service use some of the mock back-end service, and the other part service try to call real background to achieve service.I registered in the app.module custom BackendProvider.The client want to call real background service, but was intercepted by the custom mock service, how to achieve coexistence?

Comment: Can you formalize your question it's kind of hard to figure out exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

To mock backend service, you can use [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server). To manage the coexistence between mocked services and real services, you can use some constant in [environment.ts](http://tattoocoder.com/angular-cli-using-the-environment-option/), the file that contains environment configuration